# LightTable not connecting/evalling a Clojure project

Tags: clojure, leiningen, lighttable

Just starting a new Clojure project and running into some issues getting LightTable to play nicely. The app/REPL spin up fine with `lein ring server` / `lein repl` etc, but trying to connect to any file in LightTable just keeps the blue spinner…spinning…even after it says it's connected.

These are my deps (with LightTable 1.5.4 - just updated from 1.4.something which was doing the same thing)

```
(defproject clollo "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
                 [compojure "1.1.5"]
                 [trello "0.1.1-SNAPSHOT"]]
  :plugins [[lein-ring "0.8.5"]]
  :ring {:handler clollo.handler/app}
  :profiles
  {:dev {:dependencies [[ring-mock "0.1.5"]]}})
```

Files in question are

```
(ns clollo.handler
  (:use compojure.core)
  (:require [compojure.handler :as handler]
            [compojure.route :as route]
            [trello.core]))

(defroutes app-routes
  (GET "/" [] "Hello Wo1rld")
  (route/resources "/")
  (route/not-found "Not Found"))

(def app
  (handler/site app-routes))

(+ 1 1) ;; test LightTable eval!
```

I then tried getting rid of all the requires etc for debugging, so I have a new file

```
(ns clollo.ihopethisworks)

(+ 1 1) ;; this doesn't work either
```

Any ideas? As I say, LightTable's `InstaRepl` works fine on its own, and LightTable *is* connecting to this project's `project.clj` in the connect window. Just spinning when it tries to eval anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From testing your sample code, it looks like the `[trello.core]` require item, in the handler.clj file, is causing the issue. The library seems to have an issue with initializing `clj-http` in Light Table.

Also, there is an issue, with LT v0.5.x, where the working indicator, in some cases, keeps spinning after the operation is complete. You can use the `Statusbar: Reset working indicator` command to stop it.